# trying to create a simple 'mastermind-like' game

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I've been working on this simple numeric [mastermindlike](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_%28board_game%29) game. At the moment, I have the correct_number_correct_spot counter working, but not the the correct_number_wrong_spot counter. I'm still getting odd readings, and I can't figure out whats causing the errors. Here is the code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mastermind.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="doSomeShit();">

    Submit Guess:<input type="text" id="guess">
    <button id="submit_button">Submit</button>
<div id="mymoves">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and the js:

```
var right_answer=[1,2,3,4];
var max_turn= 12;
var current_turn=0;
var player_guess= [];

function make_move(guess){
    var myguess = document.getElementById("mymoves");

    var correct_number_correct_spot= 0;
    var correct_number_wrong_spot= 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        console.log(guess.split("").contains(i));
        if(right_answer[i] == guess[i])
            ++correct_number_correct_spot;
        else if(right_answer[i] !== guess[i] && guess.split("").contains(i))
            ++correct_number_wrong_spot;
        }




    myguess.innerHTML += correct_number_correct_spot + " were right!" +correct_number_wrong_spot+ "there but not in the right order";

}

Array.prototype.contains = function(obj) {
    var i = this.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (this[i] == obj) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function doSomeShit(){
    var btn = document.getElementById("submit_button");
    btn.onclick = function(){ // this makes button clickable
        var x = document.getElementById("guess").value; // gets the input value
        make_move(x);
    }
}
```

Right now, my correct_number_correct_spot checker is working, however my correct_number_wrong_spot counter is off, and is not working correctly in the for loop. In other words, it seems to be missing checks and not corresponding to the guess which is entered. In other words, the default answer right now is [1,2,3,4] so if enter 1234, it should say 4 were right!" 0 there but not in the right order. If I enter 4321 it should say 0 were right! 4 there but not in the right order. ect.
EDIT** I did end up getting it working better but still not completely, with this code from jquery:

i did get it working mostly with jquery with this code: if(answ[i] == guess[i]){

```
++correct_number_correct_spot;
            }
        else if(answ[i] !== guess[i] && $.inArray(guess[i], answ) !== -1){
            ++correct_number_wrong_spot;
           }
```

the only problem now is that when say the answer is [3,6,7,8] and you guess say 9,3,3,0, it will tell you that you have 2 there but not right order. So its still off.

Comment: You need to provide much more details, otherwise it will be closed as "Off Topic": Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: is that more clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(right_answer[i] !== guess[i] && guess.split("").contains(i)
```

This seems to check whether the very value `i` is contained in `guess`. This is quite strange, because `i` is just an index from 0 to 3, not the actual digit. I think this should be

```
if(right_answer[i] !== guess[i] && guess.split("").contains(right_answer[i])
```

Also I would suggest you to split your code into two parts: first split the `guess` so that it has the same format as `right_answer` (i.e. is an array), and only then calculate the answer.